# I need to upgrade one of my regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

Currently i use the following regular expression to validate a textArea in JSF:

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$)?"
```

It allows me to have multiple words and also uppercase and lower case characters, but still not enough, i need to make it better. It should also allow just a few special characters. Do you have any idea, how could i tune it to be able to:

-Allow the following 4 characters  `,` `.` `;` `:`

-Allow also special letters from a non english alphabet, This are the letters that are needed: `Đ` `đ` `Ž` `ž` `Ć` `ć` `Č` `č` `Š` `š`

I configured my web-app to use UTF-8, if the regular expresion could just allow those special letters, that would be great, because there would be less coding to validate each field every time.

Comment: You should read some regular expressions documentation (like http://www.regular-expressions.info/). Anyone with a basic knowledge of regular expressions can do this. -1 for a very poorly researched question.

Comment: Are you sure you only want to allow those few?

Comment: @Martinho Frenandes Thanks for your comment, and thanks for the link, i will read that. Also thanks for the -1. I deserved it :)

Comment: @Tim ,Yes those characters are all i need. :)

Comment: your Imput/OutputStream must be Encoded to the Unicode (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) with correct Charset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add them to the character-set marked with `[]`

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9,.;:ĐđŽžĆćČčŠš]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ,.;:ĐđŽžĆćČčŠš]+$)?"
```

Apart from your question, a suggestion for performance improvement: The first part is probably so the reg-exp may start with one of the allowed characters but space. As that is a special case for only the first character, remove the + sign. That way, it will match only the first character. Succeeding chars will be matched by the second part anyway.

```
"^([a-zA-Z0-9,.;:ĐđŽžĆćČčŠš][a-zA-Z0-9 ,.;:ĐđŽžĆćČčŠš]+$)?"
```

Comment: So the second one will allow the text to start with a blank(space)? It easily could happen that someone by mistake hits space as the first character, that input should be allowed too.

Comment: No, the second one is just a simplification of the first one, for efficiency. As you can see the first-letter special case is still checked for with the first character set `[]`. Then the rest is checked with a character set `[]` with the same characters but also including space, which is not expected once like the first set (no multiplicity) but an undefined number of times but at least once (`+`). You probably want to use a `*` which also allows zero times to allow single-character-strings.

Comment: if i change it to: `^([a-zA-Z0-9 ,.;:ĐđŽžĆćČčŠš][a-zA-Z0-9 ,.;:ĐđŽžĆćČčŠš]+$)?` (Notice i added a blank in first letter)Should it be able to allow blank space at beginning?

Comment: It would then, yes, but could be optimized yet again by removing the first character set as it is the same as the second one. You could then put adequate multiplicity to the second character set (minimum and maximum number of characters of that set).

Comment: For further simplification, you can add a negative lookbehind to ignore the space. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the special characters are all from the same unicode bock you can match them with the expression [`\p{InGreek}`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubc), replacing `Greek` with the block the characters come from. You can also use a negative lookbehind to prevent matching a leading space. This would make the regex:

```
^(?! )[\p{Alnum}\p{InLatinExtendedA},.;: ]+$
```

If you'd rather not fail fast on a leading space, as your comments suggest, you can use this regex to trim leading and trailing whitespace as well:

```
^\s*([\p{Alnum}\p{InLatinExtendedA},.;: ]+?)\s*$
```

The first capturing group will be the valid string without leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is interesting, where can i find the avaliable InLanguage name for Serbian-latin alphabet?

Comment: @sfrj: Looks like the block name is `Latin Extended-A`. That either means you want `\p{InLatinExtendedA}`, or `\p{InLatinExtended-A}`. Of course, that would also allow [all these characters](http://unicodinator.com/#Block-Latin_Extended-A).

Comment: No it is the first one, i just checked. Thanks :)